# Consulta MySQL demasiado lenta

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta bastante larga... genera un reporte final, se darán cuenta que son consultas a varias tablas a la vez. El resultado está bien, pero en el servidor que se ejecuta tarda demasiado y de hecho cuando hay muchos registros marca error 500.... leí acerca de stored procedure pero no entiendo para que me podría servir a mí eso.
¿alguien tiene alguna idea de que hacer para que la consulta no sea demasiada tardada, o al menos si me devuelva una respuesta?

```
SELECT d.id_ot AS OT,
d.id AS Partida,
d.razon AS motivo_urgencia,
d.comentarios,

CONCAT(
    IF(
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(produccion_comentarios.date_created, "#", users.nombre, "#", produccion_comentarios.comentario, "#", produccion_comentarios.type,"#", depto_por_suc.nombre ORDER BY produccion_comentarios.date_created DESC SEPARATOR "&")

        FROM produccion_comentarios 
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=produccion_comentarios.id_usr_gama 
        LEFT JOIN movim_prod ON movim_prod.id=produccion_comentarios.id_movim_prod 
        LEFT JOIN depto_por_suc ON depto_por_suc.id=movim_prod.id_depto 
        WHERE produccion_comentarios.id_produccion=p_m.id_produccion 
        AND produccion_comentarios.estatus=1 ORDER BY produccion_comentarios.date_created DESC) IS NULL,"",
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(produccion_comentarios.date_created, "#", users.nombre, "#", produccion_comentarios.comentario, "#", produccion_comentarios.type, "#", depto_por_suc.nombre ORDER BY produccion_comentarios.date_created DESC SEPARATOR "&")

        FROM produccion_comentarios

        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = produccion_comentarios.id_usr_gama

        LEFT JOIN movim_prod ON movim_prod.id = produccion_comentarios.id_movim_prod

        LEFT JOIN depto_por_suc ON depto_por_suc.id = movim_prod.id_depto

        WHERE produccion_comentarios.id_produccion = p_m.id_produccion

        AND produccion_comentarios.estatus = 1 ORDER BY produccion_comentarios.date_created DESC)
    ) ,"&" ,
    d.creacion,"#",us3.nombre,"#",d.comentarios,"#solicitud","#Customer Service"
) AS comentarios_completos,

prodxcli.codigo,
d.cantidad,
d.creacion,
d.fecha_progra,
d.fecha_entrega,
d.finalizacion,
CASE when d.urgencia = 1 then "NORMAL"
when d.urgencia = 2 then "URGENTE"
when d.urgencia = 3 then "PRIORIDAD"
END AS partida_urgencia,

CASE when d.estatus = 1 then "Pendiente"
when d.estatus = 2 then "Programado"
when d.estatus = 3 then "Terminado"
END AS partida_estatus,

p_m.creacion AS p_m_creacion,
p_m.fecha_inicio AS p_m_inicio,
p_m.fecha_tentativa AS p_m_tentativa,
p_m.finalizacion AS p_m_finalizacion,
CASE when p_m.estatus_prod = 0 then "Por recibir"
when p_m.estatus_prod = 1 then "Pendiente"
when p_m.estatus_prod = 2 then "Produciendo"
when p_m.estatus_prod = 3 and p_m.receptor = null then "Terminado"
when p_m.estatus_prod = 3 and p_m.receptor != null then "Enviado"
when p_m.estatus_prod = 5 then "Rechazado"
END AS p_m_estatus,
p_m.cant_sol AS p_m_cant_sol,
p_m.enviadas AS p_m_enviadas,
p_m.recibidas AS p_m_recibas,
p_m.terminadas AS p_m_terminadas,
p_m.reposicion AS p_m_reposicion,
p_m.sol_reposicion AS p_m_sol_reposicion,
p_m_d_e.nombre AS p_m_deptoemisor,
p_m_d_r.nombre AS p_m_deptoreceptor,

u_m.creacion AS u_m_creacion,
u_m.fecha_inicio AS u_m_inicio,
u_m.fecha_tentativa AS u_m_tentativa,
u_m.finalizacion AS u_m_finalizacion,
CASE when u_m.estatus_prod = 0 then "Por recibir"
when u_m.estatus_prod = 1 then "Pendiente"
when u_m.estatus_prod = 2 then "Produciendo"
when u_m.estatus_prod = 3 and u_m.receptor = null then "Terminado"
when u_m.estatus_prod = 3 and u_m.receptor != null then "Enviado"
when u_m.estatus_prod = 5 then "Rechazado"
END AS u_m_estatus,

u_m.cant_sol AS u_m_cant_sol,
u_m.enviadas AS u_m_enviadas,
u_m.recibidas AS u_m_recibas,
u_m.terminadas AS u_m_terminadas,
u_m.reposicion AS u_m_reposicion,
u_m.sol_reposicion AS u_m_sol_reposicion,
u_m_d_e.nombre AS u_m_deptoemisor,
u_m_d_r.nombre AS u_m_deptoreceptor,
u_m_d_r.id AS u_m_deptoreceptor_id,

ot.oc AS OC,

CASE when ot.estatus = 1 then "Pendiente"
when ot.estatus = 3 then "Terminado"
when ot.estatus = 2 then "Cancelado"
END AS ot_estatus,

clientes.nombre AS cliente

FROM det_ot AS d
LEFT JOIN prodxcli ON prodxcli.id=d.id_producto
LEFT JOIN produccion AS p ON p.id_det_ot=d.id

LEFT JOIN movim_prod AS p_m ON p_m.id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM movim_prod WHERE id_produccion=p.id)
LEFT JOIN depto_por_suc AS p_m_d_e ON p_m_d_e.id=p_m.emisor
LEFT JOIN depto_por_suc AS p_m_d_r ON p_m_d_r.id=p_m.id_depto

LEFT JOIN movim_prod AS u_m ON u_m.id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM movim_prod WHERE id_produccion=p.id)
LEFT JOIN depto_por_suc AS u_m_d_e ON u_m_d_e.id=u_m.emisor
LEFT JOIN depto_por_suc AS u_m_d_r ON u_m_d_r.id=u_m.id_depto
LEFT JOIN ot ON ot.id=d.id_ot
LEFT JOIN users us3 ON us3.id = ot.id_creador 

LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.id=ot.id_cliente
```

Comment: as intentando crear indices para que tu query sea mas rapida, ver que tabla impacta mas en la consulta cuanto registros busca?

Comment: Tú tienes el típico caso de una consulta que es insostenible en el tiempo, la vieja costumbre de crear un reporte solo a SQL y que retorne el reporte completo en un paso. Aquí seguro te darán las recomendaciones obvias que indexes y que crees funciones. Yo votaré por cerrar tu pregunta porque tu problema no es reproducible y nadie podrá dar una respuesta comprobada. A mí, cuando me toca arreglar este tipo de consultas, ni las leo, pregunto qué es lo que se requiere y hago todo de cero, y generalmente ocupo una capa de software (PHP, JAVA, .NET) que me permita ordenar y segmentar el problema

Comment: Usa [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/) para darte cuenta del tiempo que tarda cada parte de tu consulta y descubrir como podrías mejorarla

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta se ve bien no tiene errores ahora para determinar por que esta lenta revisa.

- primero si todos los id de tabla con los que haces los joins tienen indices, los indices son necesarios si no es que indispensables para realizar un join entre cada tabla, si es clave primaria con mas razón.
- segundo debes revisar los procesos colgados en la base de datos, veo que haces bastantes joins con varias tablas si son en ambiente de producción y suceden transacciones en las tablas mientras realizas consultas sobre registros que son actualizados, eliminados e insertados sobre esa tabla esto crea bloqueos sobre registros que deben esperar a que se liberen para consultar ese registro por lo que un ambiente de pruebas o un ambiente de consulta es mejor tenerlo solo para eso.
- tercero reinicia de vez en cuando tu servidor, esto libera procesos colgados y restablece el uso de memoria, no es recomendable si realizas tareas de monitoreo para tuneo de base de datos pero si aun no estas en ese proceso al puro estilo de los médicos con el paracetamol, los informaticos lo resolvemos reiniciando.

suerte!